# Reproducing SPSS GLM in R, changed coefficients

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, spss

I'm trying to reproduce a generalized linear model in R. The original SPSS model has distribution Gamma, link Log, with a continuous dependent variable and all independent variables categorical.

In R this should be:

```
glm(dependent_variable~.,data=data_for_SPSS_input,family=Gamma(link='log'))
```

But the coefficient estimates here don't match the ones from the SPSS output (B values) and the significant variables aren't all the same either.

The SPSS model also gives tests of model effects for the original categorical variables (rather than just the dummy coded levels) using the Wald Chi-squared test. How do I obtain these in R?

How are 'deviance', 'scaled deviance' and so on in SPSS comparable to R's null deviance and residual deviance?

Appreciate any help at all.

Comment: This is somewhat off topic here - try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.

Comment: Check if R uses the same contrasts as SPSS (probably not). Check out `anova(yourModel)` in R.

Comment: Hi Roland, can that affect the coefficients too?

@eli-k I'll try my luck there too, thanks.

Comment: Can you show some of the coefficients and their standard errors from both programs?

Answer (score 1):

Let's try below code in R and think contrasts methods. In default, R uses `contr.treatment` in treating unordered categorical variables. (It contrasts each level with the baseline level (alphabetical first);  `?contr.treatment` gives you details.)

In this example, baseline level is species *setosa*, so coefficients: `(Intercept)` and `Sepal.Length` are *setosa*'s intercept and slope and their `t value` comes from the difference between *setosa*'s intercept (or  slope) and zero. `(Intercept) + Speciesversicolor` is *versicolor*'s intercept, `Sepal.Length + Sepal.Length:Speciesversicolor` is its slope. Their `t value` comes from the difference between *versicolor* and *setosa*.

```
options()$contrasts  # return now options (I think your options are default.)

res1 <- glm(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length * Species, data=iris, family=gaussian)
# this is  equivalent to glm(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length * Species, data=iris, contrasts = list(Species="contr.treatment"), family=gaussian)

res2 <- glm(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length * Species, data=iris, contrasts = list(Species="contr.sum"), family=gaussian)

summary(res1)  # contr.treatment (Base level is Species setosa)
# Coefficients:
#                                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)                      0.8031     0.5310   1.512    0.133      Setosa's intercept
# Sepal.Length                     0.1316     0.1058   1.244    0.216      Setosa's slope
# Speciesversicolor               -0.6179     0.6837  -0.904    0.368      Difference between Setosa's intercept and versicolor's
# Speciesvirginica                -0.1926     0.6578  -0.293    0.770    
# Sepal.Length:Speciesversicolor   0.5548     0.1281   4.330 2.78e-05 ***  Difference between Setosa's slope and versicolor's
# Sepal.Length:Speciesvirginica    0.6184     0.1210   5.111 1.00e-06 ***

# If you want versicolor's Coefficients,
res1$coefficients[1] + res1$coefficients[3]   # versicolor's intercept
res1$coefficients[2] + res1$coefficients[5]   # versicolor's slope


summary(res2)  # contr.sum
# Coefficients:
#                       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)            0.53288    0.26206   2.033   0.0439 *    mean of three species' intercepts
# Sepal.Length           0.52273    0.04698  11.127  < 2e-16 ***  mean of three species' slopes
# Species1               0.27017    0.40333   0.670   0.5040    
# Species2              -0.34776    0.36121  -0.963   0.3373    
# Sepal.Length:Species1 -0.39110    0.07707  -5.075 1.18e-06 ***
# Sepal.Length:Species2  0.16374    0.06283   2.606   0.0101 *  

res2$coef[1] + res2$coef[3]  # setosa's intercept
res2$coef[1] + res2$coef[4]  # versicolor's intercept
res2$coef[1] - res2$coef[3] - res2$coef[4]  # virginica's intercept


# tests of model effects for the original categorical variables
summary(aov(res1))       # Type I Anova (This is inappropriate because this data isn't orthogonal)

# When your model doesn't have an interaction term, type II Anova is equivalent to type III (this example model has an interaction term).
library(car)
Anova(res1, type="II")
Anova(res2, type="II")   # These are equivalent. Type II Anova doesn't depend on methods of contrasts.

Anova(res1, type="III")  # These aren't equivalent !!
Anova(res2, type="III")  # When you use type III Anova, you must use contr.sum.


# tests of the models against one another
res1.2 <- glm(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length + Species, data=iris, family=gaussian)
# You needn't mind methods of contrasts and types of anova because of the same residual deviance.
anova(res1, res1.2)    # not "A"nova
```

Comment: Can you add some text to explicate this?